# Combination Matrix while keeping original matrices

Tags: r, matrix, combinations

I have an already made function that takes matrices as it's two inputs. So what I am trying to do is to create a two column matrix or list or something that has all combinations of my input matrices.

I have tried `combn()` and `expand.grid` but these both seem to expand my matrix input in their outputs. Which is not what I need since I need to store my input matrices so I can call them later.

I have for example:

```
a = c(1,2,3)

b = c(4,5,6)

c = c(7,8,9)

d = c(10,11,12)
```

And I would want an output that displays something like:

```
[a, b]

[a, c]

[a, d]

[b, c]

[b, d]

[c, d]
```

Notice I am keeping the original matrices and not comparing what is inside the matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `combn` to do that.  Get the objects into a `list` with `mget` and then select the combination of two elements at at time with `combn`

```
combn(mget(letters[1:4]), 2, simplify = FALSE)
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$a
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[1]]$b
#[1] 4 5 6


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$a
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]$c
#[1] 7 8 9

#...
```

Comment: Well the names I'm using in my actual code are a little more abstract than just letters. I used letters just as an example, so I don't think using the letters function will work for me.

Comment: @Beebs I also used that just to show the objects.  If you want to do it differently, then `mget(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))`

Comment: Also, if these are the only objects created in the environment `mget(ls())` would be more easier

Comment: @Beebs I don't get your output.  For me, I showed the output exactly as I am getting